# Keyclock / Angular 4 : Get roles or group of users

Tags: angular, keycloak

How can I get roles and group users in angular 4 when he authenticated ? 
I can acces userProfile and userInfo with keycloak.js, but I can't get roles or group..

Thx for help

Comment: It's for python but perhaps it helps to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612535/python-keycloak-get-roles-and-groups-of-user