# Python Keycloak Get Roles and Groups of user

Tags: python, keycloak

Using [Key Cloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) created groups and assigned roles to the groups. 
Than created the users and assigned the users to specific groups.

To access all this in my application I am using [Python-Keycloak](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-keycloak%20to%20access%20the%20keycloak)

As mentioned in  [github doc](https://bitbucket.org/agriness/python-keycloak/src), using following code to access the user information.

```
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID

keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                    client_id="account",
                    realm_name="demo",
                    client_secret_key="my_secret_key")

config_well_know = keycloak_openid.well_know()

token = keycloak_openid.token("username", "password")
userinfo = keycloak_openid.userinfo(token['access_token'])
```

Getting following userinfo

```
{
    'family_name': 'Lastname', 
    'preferred_username': 'user_name', 
    'sub': 'some_key', 
    'given_name': 'Fistname', 
    'name': 'Firstname Lastname', 
    'email': 'email@example.com'
}
```

How can I access the group and roles information of the user.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use "KeycloakAdmin" class in the same library (python-keycloak):

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin

admin = KeycloakAdmin(server_url='https://server-url',
                      username='username',
                      password='password',
                      realm_name='realm',
                      verify=True)

user_groups = admin.get_user_groups(user_id="user-id")
```

For use KeycloakAdmin, you will need of a user with access to "admin-cli".

Comment: This dies trying to get token (with my credentials, of course):
`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_admin.py in __init__
        self.get_token() …

Local vars

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_admin.py in get_token
        self._token = self.keycloak_openid.token(self.username, self.password, grant_type=grant_type) …

   Local vars

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_openid.py in token
        return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError) `

Comment: And with backslash at the end of server_url it gives this error: `Exception Value: 
401: b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}'`. My user is admin

Comment: you need to config the client key,
1. make sure  "Service Accounts Enabled"
2. assign client roles to it -> realm-management client role -> view-users

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Keycloak, select you client -> Mapper -> Create.
2. In a Mapper Type list select "Group Membership".
3. In Token Claim Name field specify desired userinfo property name, e.g. "Groups".
4. In Name field specify whatever you want for mapper name and click Save.
5. Try again authenticating to Keycloak with your app. User groups should now be 
   visible in userinfo JSON.

Comment: Interesting solution.  So this is essentially adding custom fields to the 'userinfo' response object with role, or group, or other available info. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Vasily Angapov Where is the value "Groups" for Token Claim Name field came from? I am trying to figure out what would be the equivalent of it for social-auth-app-django package.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Cleanest of them all.

Answer (score 2):

Created one admin user for my realm. and inherit  the class like this

```
from keycloak import KeycloakAdmin
from keycloak.exceptions import raise_error_from_response, KeycloakGetError

class CustomKeycloakAdmin(KeycloakAdmin):
    def get_user_group(self,user_name):
        USER_GROUP_URL = "admin/realms/{realm-name}/users/{user-id}/groups"
        params_path = {"user-id":self.get_user_id(user_name),"realm-name": self.realm_name}
        data_raw = self.connection.raw_get(USER_GROUP_URL.format(**params_path))
        return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError)

if __name__=="__main__":
    keycloak_admin = CustomKeycloakAdmin(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",username='admin_user',password='admin_password',realm_name="my_realm",verify=True)
    user_group = keycloak_admin.get_user_group("user_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to set the realm or client role in Keycloak for the user.
Once you set you will automatically get the role details in ‘user_groups ‘

Cheers
SG

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the keycloak API's to retrieve the particular user Group and Role details

Example CURL to get the Group details:
`GET /{realm}/users/{id}/groups`

```
curl 'http://keycloak.local:8000/auth/admin/realms/master/groups?first=0&max=20' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <access_token>' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

You can refer to the keycloak official documentation for the **Users API** [keycloak Website](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)